# Exit search with MsgBox "No" button

Tags: excel, vba

I search for text in another Excel sheet. I cannot stop the search. It keeps finding next till it goes through everything.

I would like to press the <kbd>no</kbd> button on the MsgBox to exit the loop.

```vb
Sub FindWONumber ()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("All Projects").Select
    Range("A4").Select

    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim ProjectName As Range
    Dim WorkOrderNumber As String
    Dim FirstProjectName As String

    WorkOrderNumber = InputBox("Type in Work Order Number")
    Set SearchRange = Range("B3", Range("B4").End(xlDown))
    Set ProjectName = SearchRange.FIND(What:=WorkOrderNumber, MatchCase:=False, LookAt:=xlPart)

    If ProjectName Is Nothing Then

        Sheets("Display Buttons").Select
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 85
        Range("W12").Select
        MsgBox "No Work Order Number was found"

    Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        ProjectName.Select
        FirstProjectName = ProjectName.Address

        Do
            Set ProjectName = SearchRange.FindNext(ProjectName)
            ProjectName.Select

            Dim ButtonClicked As VbMsgBoxResult

            ButtonClicked = MsgBox("Find Next", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, Title:="Search String")

        Loop While ProjectName.Address <> FirstProjectName

        If ButtonClicked = vbYes Then
            MsgBox "Search Complete"
        ElseIf ButtonClicked = vbNo Then
            MsgBox "Stop"

        Else
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the code. You have a logic error that the debugger will make clear to you really quickly.

Comment: Your ButtonClicked condition merely directs the program to MsgBox commands. These have no effect on the code progression.

Comment: I stepped through the code with the F8 button and i do not know how to exit the loop when i press the no button. Can you assist?

Answer (score 0):

I re-indented your code (shown below) and added a few explanatory comments. Hopefully now, it's easier to see the logic-flow in your code.

Focusing just within the `Else` statement for the first `If-Else` code block, you change the screen updating to true, then set the variable for the `FirstProjectName`. After this you have a `Do-Loop` where you find next, and ask to continue (storing the result from the msgbox). Then the code compares the project names and loops if the condition is met. After the loops have completely finished, then you have logic (another `If-Else` statement) to look at the result from the msgbox, and do conditional coding based on that result.

Since you want the result from the msgbox to affect the `Do-Loop` (only continue looping if result is `vbYes`), you should change:

```
Loop While ProjectName.Address <> FirstProjectName
```

to:

```
Loop While ProjectName.Address <> FirstProjectName And ButtonClicked = vbYes
```

(I would also shift the declaration of the msgbox result variable, `Dim ButtonClicked As VbMsgBoxResult` towards the beginning of the code with the other variable declarations.)

**Original Code**

---

```
Sub FindWONumber ()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("All Projects").Select
    Range("A4").Select

    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim ProjectName As Range
    Dim WorkOrderNumber As String
    Dim FirstProjectName As String

    WorkOrderNumber = InputBox("Type in Work Order Number")
    Set SearchRange = Range("B3", Range("B4").End(xlDown))
    Set ProjectName = SearchRange.FIND(What:=WorkOrderNumber, MatchCase:=False, LookAt:=xlPart)

    If ProjectName Is Nothing Then

        Sheets("Display Buttons").Select
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 85
        Range("W12").Select
        MsgBox "No Work Order Number was found"

    Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        ProjectName.Select
        FirstProjectName = ProjectName.Address

        ' Start of loop
        Do
            Set ProjectName = SearchRange.FindNext(ProjectName)
            ProjectName.Select

            Dim ButtonClicked As VbMsgBoxResult

            ButtonClicked = MsgBox("Find Next", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, Title:="Search String")

        ' End of loop
        Loop While ProjectName.Address <> FirstProjectName

        ' Done after loop above has finished
        If ButtonClicked = vbYes Then
            MsgBox "Search Complete"
        ElseIf ButtonClicked = vbNo Then
            MsgBox "Stop"

        Else
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I want to Thank you very much for explaining it and writing the descriptive lines.

Comment: I was not aware i can do the "And" comment you recommended.  The logic now makes much more sense.  I appreciate it very much.....and the explanation.